# Alarm App in Wpf

Tags: wpf, multithreading

i try to create an app that alarm for list of reminders in background and even after shutdown the app, alarm part still work and alarm for top reminder.
which is the best approach(dispatcher, BackgroundWorker, TPL ....) ?
thank for your attention.﻿

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep your app alive to execute code. You could use the C# `Timer` class for simple implementations or a scheduler like [Quartz.NET](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet) if you need a more complex solution.

If it's absolutely necessary for you to close your app, you could also build a solution based on the Windows Task Scheduler.

Of course, this list isn't complete, I just wanted to give some ideas ;)